# .NET assembly name contains dot

Tags: c#, .net, naming

I'm trying to use a .NET assembly that has a dot in its name, but it doesn't work.
The assembly's name is PylonC.Net. For example, my code starts with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PylonC.Net;
```

If I compile it (with C# compliler csc.exe that comes with MS VS2010 Express) I get this error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PylonC' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I checked that PylonC.Net is in the cache with gacutil:

> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>   PylonC.Net, Version=4.0.1.3425, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a77e8471c5919d 5a, processorArchitecture=MSIL

If I check the cache for PylonC I get this:

> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>
> Number of items = 0

It appears to me that the dot in the assembly's name is making the compiler look for Net inside PylonC, instead of an assembly named PylonC.Net.

The PylonC.Net assembly is provided by Basler for controlling their FireWire camera. I cannot change its name or find a replacement.

I tried to get support from Basler but it's very difficult, since we bought their camera as a part of a system from a third party supplier. Basler doesn't give support directly, but rather via local representatives, and the representatives only support their customers (i.e. people who bought the Basler camera through them). The third party supplier is in a different country than me...

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thank you,

Gil

Comment: On top of my head you could use some IL disassembler (e.g. DotPeek by JetBrains) to pek into the assembly itself and obtain it's actual name.

Answer (score 8):

Seems like you forgot to add a reference to the PylonC.Net assembly in your project.

Also, namespaces and assembly names are two very different things. Both can contain dots, and most of the time they do contain many dots. (Namespaces mostly start with the name of the assembly, but only by convention.)

Comment: Thanks! You were absolutely right. I should have mentioned that I'm a .NET lamer... Anyway, for completeness and future reference, here is how to call compiler properly: csc SimpleGrab.cs /reference:"C:\Program Files\Basler\pylon 4\pylonc.net\bin\PylonC.NET.dll"

Comment: You can add the reference in Visual Studio: right click on project -> add reference. In the end, it will end up as a /reference parameter to the csc.exe, but it's much better to develop code and maintain the projects in Visual Studio.